# Python regex capture group containing nested non-capturing group

Tags: python-regex

I'm trying to capture string-parts `Abbb`, `Abb`, `Ab`, `A`, `C###`, `C#`, `C`, etc. into one group and whatever follows (anything that's not `b`, `#`) into a separate group.
I'm using this regex:

```
sample = "Cbb-7" # for testing purposes
re.search(r"([A-G](?:#*|b*))(.*?)", sample).groups()
```

which [results](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5BA-G%5D(%3F%3A%23*%7Cb*))(.*%3F)&test_string=Cbb-7&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) in:
`('C', '')`
while I'm expecting:
`('Cbb', '-7')`.

When modifying the regex to (greedy follow-up capture group`(.*)`):

```
re.search(r"([A-G](?:#*|b*))(.*)", sample).groups()
```

I get the [result](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5BA-G%5D(%3F%3A%23*%7Cb*))(.*)&test_string=Cbb-7&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0):
`('C', 'bb-7')`. (I still would need: `('Cbb','-7')`)

Answer (score 0):

Moving optionality of `b`, `#`out of the non-capturing group seems to help:

```
re.search(r"([A-G](?:#+|b+)?)(.*)", sample).groups()
```

[results](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5BA-G%5D(%3F%3A%23%2B%7Cb%2B)%3F)(.*)&test_string=Cbb-7&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) in:

`('Cbb', '-7')` Still wondering why!